# How to join common dates on a TemporalData set with TimeSeriesThread (possible Bug)

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, time-series

**Bug introduced in version 13.2 or earlier**

*WRI have forwarded the problem to their developers. Case Number 5029803*

---

I am trying to join `TemporalData` with many paths into an equivalent `TimeSeries`/`EventSeries` with a single path. (so I can perform `MovingMap` on it). Let's get some data:

```
days = DayRange["2023-05-01", "2023-05-07"]
values = ConstantArray[#, Length[days]] & /@ Range[3]
valuesES = EventSeries[#, {days}] & /@ values
```

[image]

Now we can join it with `TimeSeriesThread` and the `Identity` function. This is the intended and expected result.

```
TimeSeriesThread[Identity, valuesES]
% // Values
```

[image]

**Here comes the problem.**

From the documentation :

> "The collection of paths {tseries1,tseries2,...} can equivalently be given as TemporalData[{tseries1,tseries2,...}]."

So we would expect the following code to produce the same results as above but we get an error message and it fails to evaluate. It is counting 7 paths instead of 3.

```
valuesTD = TemporalData[valuesES]
TimeSeriesThread[Identity, valuesTD]
```

[image]

But when we try this with a different function, say `Apply[Plus]` instead of `Identity`, it behaves as expected

```
TimeSeriesThread[Apply[Plus], valuesTD]
%["Values"]
```

[image]

**Why is this the case and how should I apply `TimeSeriesThread` correctly on `TemporalData`?**

Comment: I have reported this to Wolfram Technical Support

Comment: Wolfram have confirmed not desired behaviour and sent it to their developers